# PollSlider hide, animate, hide

Tags: jquery-animate, hide

I'm just following on from a previous post about a pollslider - see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/3/

I'm trying to get the pollSlider div to be hidden initially, when you click the pollSlider-button the pollSlider div is made visible, then animated into position. Then when the button is clicked again for the pollSlider div to animate and then hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).css("margin-right") == "200px")
    {
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});
    }
    else
    {
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'});
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'});
    }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate your poll width and not margin-right. Something like this:

[**MY FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/XNnHC/594/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).css("margin-right") == "200px")
    {
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"width": '-=200'});
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '-=200'});
    }
    else
    {
        $('.pollSlider').animate({"width": '+=200'});
        $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-right": '+=200'});
    }


  });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a massive help. - however i have content in my pollSlider div that looks odd as the width increases and decreases. I decided to put the content in another div and fade that content in after a short amount of time

Comment: setTimeout('$(".pollSliderContent").fadeTo("slow",1.0)', 500);

Comment: @user1546292 yes, you could use jquery .delay() too. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/XNnHC/596/